# Partition backup solution

Tags: backup

I am looking for a solution for partition backup and restore.  Can be a combination of software (on different platforms - using compatible formats).

Priorities in this order.

1. Reliable restore - also to different partitions than the original.  Troubleshooting if 'difficult" for some reason.
2. Live backup of active system drive Windows. If not possible, then perhaps via reboot.
3. Incremental backup possibilities.
4. Platforms: Windows, then mainstream Linux distros, then "special" Linux, Boot CDs etc.
5. Open and effective formats.

I have tried Acronis, but it refuses to restore to non-original partitions, without any further information.
I often have swap and data-files on different partition.  In the past this has made Windows native solutions want to back up several partitions.

Comment: What's an effective format?

Comment: Not in-efficient :-)

. . . One can imagine LCD formats are not efficient.